# Incorrect redirect URI in Azure authenticated Flask app when deployed using nginx and docker

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have a flask app that was built based on the following instructions that allows me to authenticate users based Azure AD.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-python-webapp

The app works great when tested on `localhost:5000`. Now I want to deploy it to a production server using docker and nginx reverse proxy. I have created a docker container so that the docker port is mapped to port 6000 on localhost. Then I have added a `proxy_pass` in nginx config to pass the traffic to the docker container.

nginx.conf

```
location /app/authenticated-app/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:6000/;
  proxy_redirect default;
}
```

With this config, I can go to the login page via `https://server/app/authenticated-app` however, when I click on login, the request that goes to azure has a query parameter `redirect_uri` that's set to `http://localhost:6000/getToken`. Therefore, once I complete the login, the app gets redirected to that url. Does anyone know how to fix this and get it redirected to the proper url. I have already added `https://server/app/authenticated-app/getToken` under the `redirect_uri` on azure portal.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, with nginx and my flask app both running in docker containers in the same stack and using a self-signed SSL certificate.

My nginx redirects requests as follow:

```
proxy_pass http://$CONTAINER_NAME:$PORT;
```

and the msal app uses that URL when building its `redirect_uri`

```
def _build_auth_code_flow(authority=None, scopes=None):
    return _build_msal_app(authority=authority).initiate_auth_code_flow(
        scopes or [],
        redirect_uri=url_for("auth.authorized", _external=True))
```

I cheated a little bit by hardcoding the return URL I wanted (which is identical to the one I configured in my azure app registration)  in my `config.py` file and using that for the `redirect_uri`:

```
def _build_auth_code_flow(authority=None, scopes=None):
    return _build_msal_app(authority=authority).initiate_auth_code_flow(
        scopes or [],
        redirect_uri=current_app.config['HARDCODED_REDIRECT_URL_MICROSOFT'])
```

In my case, that `url` would be `https://localhost/auth/redirect/`. I also needed to configure my nginx to redirect all requests from http to https:

```
events {}
http {

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://localhost$request_uri;

  }
...
```

Comment: any idea how to do this now without hardcoding the URI?

Comment: I don't, I'm still using this method and I expanded on it a little bit by having different hardcoded URLs in different app configurations for my different environments (local, test and prod), which are loaded by injecting a corresponding environment variable in my docker-compose files. It's a dirty fix but it works well enough for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, what I did is :

Use Cherrypy to enable ssl on custom port.

```
cherrypy.config.update({'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
                        'server.socket_port': 8443,
                        'engine.autoreload.on': False,
                        'server.ssl_module':'builtin',
                        'server.ssl_certificate':'crt',
                        'server.ssl_private_key':'key'
                        })
```

Then install Nginx and proxy to `https://127.0.0.1:8443`

Not sure if that will help but this what I did to get my flask app working with MSAL.